# having problems with compositeTemplates using docusign-csharp-client

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to create an envelope with multiple templates.
I am using the logic as below (Simplified) to add the templates to the envelope.

```
EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
ServerTemplate serverTemplate = new ServerTemplate();
CompositeTemplate compositeTemplate = new CompositeTemplate();

serverTemplate.TemplateId = "c081f3c4-82cf-4312-b360-4471361d7079";
serverTemplate.Sequence = "1";

compositeTemplate.ServerTemplates.Add(serverTemplate); // ERRORS

envDef.CompositeTemplates.Add(compositeTemplate);
```

My intention is to also add an inline template containing the recipients, but it errors when trying to add the server template to the composite template.
I have spent all morning googling, but cannot find any examples or similar issues. Documentation for the docusign-csharp-client is non existent and after posting a question on git  hub, I realised that I was probably unlikely to receive an answer.

Comment: Please show the corresponding JSON that you are building as I'm sure that will reveal what's wrong with the request.  You can enable request logging in your DS account, send the request, then inspect the logs.

Answer (score 1):

Even though you're only adding one template you need to add the server templates as a list with one element.  Try something like:

```
EnvelopeDefinition envDef = new EnvelopeDefinition();
ServerTemplate serverTemplate = new ServerTemplate();
CompositeTemplate compositeTemplate = new CompositeTemplate();

serverTemplate.TemplateId = "c081f3c4-82cf-4312-b360-4471361d7079";
serverTemplate.Sequence = "1";

// create one element list of server templates and add to request...
List<ServerTemplates> list = new List<ServerTemplates>() { serverTemplate };
compositeTemplate.ServerTemplates.Add(list);
```